# error on using Navlink from react-router-dom

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, react-router-dom

My Header.js file is as below:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { AppBar, Tab, Tabs, Toolbar, Typography} from "@mui/material";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Header =  () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState();
    return (
    <div>
        <AppBar sx={{ backgroundColor: "#100c09"}} position="sticky">
          <Toolbar>
              <Typography> 
                  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zGZshwK/furnica.png" height="50px" width="50px" />    
                    </Typography>
                    <Tabs textColor="inherit" indicatorColor="secondary" value={value} onChange={(e,val) => setValue(val)}>
                      <Tab LinkComponent={NavLink} to="/AboutUs" label="About Us" />
                      <Tab LinkComponent={NavLink} to="/Products" label="Products" />
                      <Tab LinkComponent={NavLink} to="/Sale" label="Sale!" />        
                    </Tabs>
          </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

My index.js is as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <React.StrictMode>
   <App />  
  </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

when i try running it, it will just give a white screen.
When i remove the NavLink part, it runs perfectly fine.
[image: Screenshot after removing navlink]

is there anything that should be added more into any other js file?

Comment: When you get a blank screen usually you have errors in console.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-on-using-navlink-from-react-router-dom-4z1u4t) and it's working without issue. *Then* I realized you are likely referring to any content the links link to, i.e. the routed content. Please include ***all relevant*** code in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.